# Formulate questions to be less suspectable as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Several of my questions were marked as duplicate, [IMHO] without justification. In the [latest example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826572/using-the-y-combinator-in-haskell), I even linked to the alleged duplicate, since my question was a follow-up.

Since the duplicate close-votes came from different people, and different tags, I presume there's something in my style which makes questions less clear and hence prone to be flagged as duplicate. One obvious solution is to use "defensive programming", i.e., actively list all related questions and for each explain how the current question is different. However, that is very tiresome.

Comment: Closely related on MSE: [Someone flagged my question as already answered but its not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476)

Comment: The linked question seems to be reopened now.

Comment: @JoshCaswell are you mocking him by hinting that yet another of his questions is a duplicate?

Comment: No, @Amit, I'm trying to help by pointing to a really good answer on another site that might provide some useful information.

Comment: @AmitGold - It's not possible to flag a post as a duplicate of something on a different SE site, including the Meta for Stack Exchange as a whole.

Comment: Regarding the "defensive programming", actively listing _all related questions_ and explaining why yours is different seems like taking something that could be reasonable to an extreme. I'm not sure about your specific question (because honestly the content is pretty incomprehensible to me) but in general if another question is sufficiently closely related that you link it as a reference, it doesn't seem unreasonable to explain in your initial question explicitly what you think is different between your question and the linked reference.

Comment: I agree that there is a lot of knee-jerk 'duplicate' labeling going on and I also find that I have to ask questions defensively to avoid that. I feel like some people love being the 'police' too much and don't take the time to see if the other post really answers the question. It would be nice if there was a way to encourage them to do so.

Comment: @user:  _"It would be nice if there was a way to encourage them to do so"_ -- Agreed. However, it would also be nice if there was a way to _discourage_ laziness when posting a question. One of the main reasons you see any sort of "knee-jerk" closing in the first place isn't so much that people _"love being the 'police'"_, but rather they feel they need to be, because *so* many other people _don't_ feel they need to bother to do any research before posting their question, never mind just find the Q&A on Stack Overflow that already has their answer. The latter people **far** outnumber the former

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What you did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36826572/revisions) is pretty good:

> This is not a duplicate of [Y Combinator in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273413/y-combinator-in-haskell). This question (which I linked to), **provides the definition of y combinator, but doesn't explain how to use it.**

If you trimmed it to:

> [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273413/y-combinator-in-haskell) **provides the definition of y combinator, but doesn't explain how to use it.**

It should be fine too. You explained that you already have seen the other question and why it doesn't answer your current question.

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry about duplicates, just ask the question that you actually have
(assuming you did have [looked around to see if your question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

If somebody flags your question as a duplicate; edit your question to explain what is the difference (as [others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/137096) [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321637/4279)).

If your question looks especially similar to another question then you could mention the difference preemptively. My personal opinion is that questions should be concise i.e., you don't need to mention all related questions even if you are aware about them—it clutters the question. But others may interpret it as the lack of the research effort—it is a general issue that a useful well-scoped "how to" question may look like "give me teh codez" question. I would start with a short clear question and add more details later if necessary.

Comment: "it is a general issue that a useful well-scoped "how to" question may look like "give me teh codez" question" - the easiest way to avoid negative vibes there is to mention an idea and why it doesn't work satisfactorily yet or mentioning what kind of research has been done and why that didn't already result in a solution. Just one or two examples should be enough.

Comment: Sometimes even one duplicate vote is too many - if it is made by a hammer-wielding person. Editing it after it was already closed would be less successful than preemptively mentioning the likely duplicate and why it isn't one.

Answer (score 6):

> Several of my questions were marked as duplicate, [IMHO] without justification

I'm curious about your idea of "several". In the last six months, I only found three questions of yours that had ever been marked as duplicate (including the one you reference here). Only one of them is still closed.

I don't have enough experience with Haskell and the questions here to comment much on the question you're referencing here, but would agree that the proposed duplicate doesn't directly address your question. Still, I did find other Haskell questions that appear to more directly address the question of dealing with the *"Couldn't match type"* error message in the context of combinators. It's possible the question really is a duplicate, just not of the one chosen when it was closed.

Further, while I'd agree that the question about Git hunk granularity was marked duplicate against the wrong question, I'd say there's a strong argument that it *is* a duplicate of [Can I split an already split hunk with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6276752) And the question about `?-mix:` in Ruby regex seems even more clearly a duplicate; it's still marked as a duplicate and the title of the marked duplicate is almost exactly the same as your title, and frankly the question is presented more clearly than yours was.

In other words, while it's possible there's been some errors made by the community, I wouldn't say your record is 100% clean either. Part of what you could improve is to do a better job posting questions that aren't already answered in some fashion on Stack Overflow.

(Though, it does seem to me that considering the number of questions you've posted, there has not been too excessive a number of those marked as duplicate. It might be a little higher than one would hope for, but I'm sure there are people with far worse records, and who need a *lot* more help in figuring out how to post a good question.)

The best thing you can do to avoid getting questions marked as duplicates is to be *very* thorough in your research. It is nearly guaranteed that you will find a number of questions at least somewhat relevant to your own; if you're sure your question isn't a duplicate of those, then go ahead and post your question but be clear at the top about what you found, how it relates to your question, and why *specifically* your question is different (i.e. simply saying *"my question isn't a duplicate of that one"* isn't going to help much).

And of course, if you're not sure the question isn't a duplicate, spend more time looking for your answer in the information your research uncovered. Quite often, your answer will be there, even though not expressed exactly the way you were hoping for.

If there's any room for improvement in your own case, it seems to me it would be that.

Even after all that effort, there's no guarantee your question won't be marked as a duplicate. One reason to go to so much effort when posting a question is that it will help differentiate you from the typical person who posts a question to Stack Overflow. But unfortunately, the flip side of that is that the typical person who posts a question is fairly sloppy and lazy, and very frequently posts a duplicate question.

For those of us who care about the quality of the site, we work aggressively to try to stem the tide of this sort of thing, but that means every now and then a good question will get caught up in the net. For what it's worth the false-positive rate is very low; the number of actual duplicate questions *far* out-numbers the number of questions incorrectly marked as a duplicate.

Fortunately, the community is usually pretty good about undoing the mistake. Frankly, if anything the community is overly generous, reopening questions that really should remain closed. But that means that for a question that *really* was mistakenly marked as a duplicate, you should be able to get it reopened reasonably quickly.